# If $X \sim\textrm{ Bin}(100, 0.5), $ then what is the approximate distribution of $(X/5 - 10)^2? $

Tags: probability, random-variable, binomial-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I am not able to solve this using transformation since binomial does not have a CDF. The question has 4 options, so I tried calculating the expectation of this and then comparing it to the expectations of the options, but none matched.
The correct answer to this is that it follows chi-square with 1 degree of freedom.
Can anyone help me understand how to approach this?

Comment: You might not know this, but you need to include the `self-study` tag to follow the rules for submission on this site. It is obvious from the context of your post that this is the case. However, that tag needs to be included explicitly.

Comment: Hello, Anweshan, welcome to CV. Please note, as already told by @Carl, that you need to add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Best wishes.

Comment: The binomial certainly possesses a CDF but I wouldn't start with the CDF in any case.

Answer (score 3):

- $X \sim \text{Binomial}(100, 0.5)$ can be [approximated by a Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) with a mean of $100 \times 0.5 = 50$ and variance of $100 \times (0.5) \times (1 - 0.5) = 25$.
- Therefore $\frac{X}{5}$ is approximately normal with a mean of 10 and a variance of $\frac{25}{5^2} =1$.
- This means $\frac{X}{5} - 10$ is a standard normal distribution, with a mean of 0 and variance of 1.
- If $X$ is a standard normal distribution, $X^2$ is a chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom.